# Failed to load data to Amazon keyspaces using COPY FROM

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, amazon-keyspaces

Just trying out Amazon's new Keyspaces (apache cassandra). Followed the directions and created a cqlsh link. Everything looks good until I try to upload data into a table. It kept telling me

```
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse https://xxx.jpg!default : invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'https://xxx.jpg!default',  given up without retries
```

It looks like the url column is considered as other columns. There are two int columns before and after this url column. I tried the exact same data file on my local cassandra. Worked just fine. Upload all the data in 3 mins.

What is the possible reason? How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason. Just post the solution in case someone else encounter the same problem.

You can't use

```
COPY table FROM 'export.csv' WITH HEADER=true AND INGESTRATE=8000 AND NUMPROCESSES=4 AND MAXBATCHSIZE=20 AND CHUNKSIZE=100
```

Although I was using the exact same table schema to create the table in Keyspaces, somehow the internal order is still different. To be safe, you can specify the order of columns

```
COPY table (id,name,xxx,...) FROM 'export.csv' WITH HEADER=true AND INGESTRATE=8000 AND NUMPROCESSES=4 AND MAXBATCHSIZE=20 AND CHUNKSIZE=100
```